# MVC View Image Drag & drop functionality

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have mvc .net core project in bootstrap 4, as you can see the image functionality is working fine however there is no drag and drop functionality in the center, if I try to drag the image on "Choose file" it works but not in the center so could you please help me with just drag and drop functionality.

**I don't want the code to upload and the image should not be uploaded to the server side, also need to ensure that there is close button on the right hand side which should remain intact.**

[image]

**JavaScript**

```
$('.img-wrap .close').on('click', function () {
  var id = $(this).closest('.img-wrap').find('imgInp').data('id');
  $('#imgInp').attr('src', '');
  $("#file").val('');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.imgdrop {
  height: 30px;
}

.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px red solid;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img-wrap .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 5px 2px 2px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .2;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-wrap:hover .close {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
@Html.Label("Image"@*, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"}*@)
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class=" imgdrop" multiple="multiple" />
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="#" alt="Alternate Image" id="imgInp" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). It does the UI for you. It will not upload without work from you.

Comment: That's good however I don't want multiple upload and want to place the image drag and drop in html appropriately not in constant place consuming half page, also I need to have close icon at the top right corner as mentioned in ask

Comment: Take a look at [Drag And Drop File Upload In ASP.NET Core](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/474dc031-087f-4b81-b994-9ca2adb949d6.aspx) for some pointers.